# How to prove $\langle E_k\rangle = \langle E_p\rangle$?

Tags: waves, oscillators

In wave physics, when deriving

$P=\frac{1}{2} \mu v y_m^2 \omega^2$

we use the fact that $\langle E_k\rangle = \langle E_p\rangle$.

I haven't seen any proof of this fact from any general physics book.

Is the proof too hard?

Could you explain briefly, please?

Or else, is there a way to derive $\langle E_p\rangle=\frac{1}{4} \mu v y_m^2 \omega^2$?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the virial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume $\mu$ is the volumic mass, and take the simple example of a wave in 1D with displacement $u= A \sin( kx-\omega t)$. Then the restoring force is of the form $-\kappa \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, the instant potential energy density stored at any $x$ is of the form :$$e_{p}=\frac{1}{2}\kappa \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\kappa A^{2}k^{2}\sin^{2}(\omega t-kx)$$ and the instant kinetic energy density is :$$e_{k}=\frac{1}{2} \mu \left(  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \right)^{2}= \frac{1}{2}\mu A^{2}\omega^{2}\sin^{2}(\omega t-kx)$$
To arrive at the desired result (after time average integration, and possibly $x$ integration over a given spatial domain) you simply need to notice that for satisfying the wave equation : $c^{2}=\omega^{2}/k^{2}=\kappa / \mu$. So indeed:
$$\left< e_{p}\right>=\frac{1}{4}\kappa A^{2}k^{2}= \frac{1}{4}A^{2}\mu\omega^{2}=\left< e_{k}\right>$$
(Note: I presume in your notation $y_{m}=A$, but I'm not sure what $v$ stands for)